# Flutter image upload to SpringBoot server not working

Tags: spring-boot, flutter

I'm trying to upload an image from my Flutter application using the following code:

```
Future<String> saveImage(File image) async {

  var stream = new http.ByteStream(DelegatingStream.typed(image.openRead()));
  var length = await image.length();
  String token = "blah"; //token for authentication

  var uri = Uri.parse(url);  //I get the URL from some config

  Map<String, String> headers = { "Authorization": "Bearer $token", "content-type": "multipart/form-data" };

  var request = new http.MultipartRequest("POST", uri);
  request.headers.addAll(headers);
  var multipartFile = new http.MultipartFile('file', stream, length);

  request.files.add(multipartFile);

  var response = await request.send();
  print(response.statusCode);
  response.stream.transform(utf8.decoder).listen((value) {
    print(value);
  });
}
```

But this request fails on my spring-boot server with the following error:

`{"timestamp":1562637369179,"status":400,"error":"Bad Request","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException","message":"Required request part 'file' is not present","path":"/api/v1/user/photo"}`

This is what my Java controller method looks like:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/photo", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadImage(@RequestPart(required = true) @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile image) throws IOException {
        }
```

I would like to mention that the method works if I use postman to upload an image.  There seems to be something wrong with my flutter code.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In `@RequestPart`  default value for `required` is `true` so you don't have to mention that and remove `@RequestParam` instead do this `@RequestPart("file")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured it out.  Instead of using the `new http.MultipartFile()` constructor I used this static method:

```
request.files.add(await http.MultipartFile.fromPath('file', image.path,
    contentType: new MediaType('image', imageType)));
```